# Pushout in Commutative $\mathbb{Z}$-Alg

Tags: category-theory, algebras

Note: Everything is commutative and unital

I am asked to determine the pushout in the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras. So far, I have shown that the pushout is a tensor product modded by the relation $(f(n) - g(n))$. Is there something I overlooked?

Comment: Does it work? I suggest you write a proof that you do get a pushout in that way and then we can see if and what you overlooked.

Comment: Yes, all algebras are commutative.

Comment: Gives essentially the same result as the generic process of taking the coproduct of the two target objects, then taking the coequalizer of two maps from the source object into this coproduct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically correct, though your notation "$f(n)-g(n)$" is not very precise and I'm not sure you have the correct thing in mind.  To be more precise, if $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to C$ are homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras, then their pushout is the quotient of the tensor product $B\otimes_\mathbb{Z} C$ by the ideal generated by all elements of the form $f(a)\otimes 1-1\otimes g(a)\in B\otimes_\mathbb{Z} C$ for $a\in A$.  This quotient is also known as the $B\otimes_A C$, the tensor product of $B$ and $C$ as $A$-algebras.

Comment: Ah, I see my confusion. Instead of having $A$ as the start point, I had $\mathbb{Z}$. Everything makes much more sense now.

Comment: That is why I suggested the OP actually tell us what he had in mind...